# Firing a click event in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm using the following code to fire a click event when another button is clicked.  It is working perfectly in Firefox.  However, in IE 8 and 9 (compatibility mode), the code is reached to fire the event, but the event never gets fired (confirmed with writes to the event log) Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

```
$('#" + cmdSaveContactDetails.ClientID + @"').click(function() {
    var areasOfInterestSaveButton = $('#ctl00_TabControl_element_AreasOfInterest_element_view_AreasOfInterest_AreasOfInterest_cmdSaveAreasOfInterest');                
    $(areasOfInterestSaveButton).click();
});
```

Event Handler:

```
private void cmdSaveAreasOfInterest_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("JR Saving", "");
}
```

Comment: Post the event-triggering code as well as the event-handling code, please ..

Comment: Check it on the client side. use alert when the second button is clicked.

Comment: Are you binding the first `.click` event handler in the `$(document).ready` event?

Comment: Does the following work: `__doPostBack('" + byButton.ClientID + "', '');` (or however you're getting the button's ID)

Comment: @Rocket: Chances are, yes. ASP applies control IDs based on container location (unless you use static IDs)

Comment: yes, rocket.  I'm working on the SalesLogix platform.  Rob - I'm pretty sure I know what jquery and javascript are at this point in my career.

Comment: Is your element's ID really `ctl00_TabControl_element_AreasOfInterest_element_view_AreasOfInterest_AreasOfInterest_cmdSaveAreasOfInterest`?

Comment: @MusicMagi: Your event handler code isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Matthew - it is registered here in my environment:  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "SaveAreasOfInterestTab", script, true);, which is the same thing is $(document).ready() - I get the same behavior if I use $(document).ready()function() { etc.

Comment: The event handler is in c# code-behind

Comment: Thanks for your responses everybody and to whomever downvoted my post

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, the proper manner to trigger an event in jQuery is by using [the `trigger()` method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$(areasOfInterestSaveButton).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that too.  Same result

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a javascript click event will not (and should not) fire your code-behind click handler. If you want to fire an event handler from the client, either move the handler to the client or use Ajax to call a web method.

Comment: The code in the handler cannot be handled on client-side.  It has to be handled on server-side.

Comment: @MusicMagi then you need to make an ajax call. You can't boundary cross without putting some work in :)

Comment: can you give me an example of how this would be done using Ajax?  Thanks for your comments

Comment: @MusicMagi i suggest you try it yourself and ask other specific questions if you run into problems.